# Exception when uploading files in SharePoint using a Windows application in C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I want to upload files in SharePoint using a Windows application in C#.

```
using (ClientContext client = new ClientContext("https://jithin32.sharepoint.com/sites/demo"))
            {
                string passWd = "myPasssword";
                SecureString securePassWd = new SecureString();
                foreach (var c in passWd.ToCharArray())
                {
                    securePassWd.AppendChar(c);
                }
                client.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("jithu@jithin32.onmicrosoft.com", 
       securePassWd);
                var formLib = client.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                var fld1 = formLib.RootFolder.Folders.Add("case2");
                var fld2 = fld1.Folders.Add("10001");
                fld1.Update();
                fld2.Update();
                client.ExecuteQuery();
            }
```

but I got the following error:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException: 
'The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system.'
```

However, these credentials work fine when I manually type them into the SharePoint site.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. Either the name or the password is wrong. This has nothing to do with uploading

Comment: I was able to log in using the same username and password

Comment: The error says you used the *wrong* username and password

Comment: I have the same issue and MFA is the issue as pointed out by LZ_MSFT. BUT... i still need an app than can be scheduled to run as a service be able to move files to sharepoint. To date, the examples i have found that work all require you to enter info.

How can this be done unattended?

Answer (score 2):

If you enable Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA), you will get the this error message.

You need install the package using command below.

```
Install-Package SharePointPnPCoreOnline -Version 3.17.2001.2
```

Then using the code below to connect SharePoint Online.

```
var authManager = new AuthenticationManager();
var client = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext("https://jithin32.sharepoint.com/sites/demo");
```

**Reference**: Office 365 : [Connecting to SharePoint online site using CSOM when Multi-Factor Authentication (MFA) is enabled for the user](https://knowledge-junction.com/2017/12/24/office-365-connecting-to-sharepoint-online-site-using-csom-when-multi-factor-authentication-mfa-is-enabled-for-the-user/)

Comment: SharePointPnPCoreOnline is deprecated and it is recommened you use PnP Framework instead (https://github.com/pnp/pnpframework)